# namespace '<global namespace>' already contains a definition for -

Tags: c#

Im very new to all this but I was trying to get a gun to shoot and I ran into this error:

> Assets\Low Poly Guns\Scripts\PlayerShoot.cs(6,14): error CS0101: The
> namespace '' already contains a definition for
> 'PlayerShoot'

Here was the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerShoot : MonoBehaviour {

    [Header("References")]
    [SerializeField] GunData gunData;

    private void start()
    {
        PlayerShoot.shootInput += Shoot; 
    }

    public void Shoot()
    {
        Debug.Log("Shot Gun!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Search your code for `PlayerShoot` you'll notice a line somewhere: `global using PlayerShoot` - either keep it there in one place, or declare it in every file you refer to it.

Comment: or place this in a namespace around your class